# Controlling a processing.js sketch w/ a jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, processing.js

I've had some luck controlling processing.js sketches using html form elements and would like to use a jQuery slider to do the same.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 37,
        min: 1,
        max: 700,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
</script>

<p>
<label for="amount">Maximum price:</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;"/>
</p>

<div id="slider-range-min"></div>
```

I think my main problem is that I don't entirely understand the slider function, how to refer to its value inside the sketch, or how to refer the window.processing.Data={}; variable inside the slider.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Jquery-ui's slider before so I'm not sure if your using it correctly. But you can easily communicate between the processing code and the javascript code by placing a variable on the window object:

1) window.communicate = {}

2) store variables on that object : window.communicate.myVar

3) alter the variables in javascript:

```
// inside jquery-ui callback
window.communicate.myVar = ui.value;
```

4) read the variables in processing

I created a a demo for you on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/Rms2N/2/

**UPDATE**

So in your slide function you can set a variable on your communicate object:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
    window.communicate.value = ui.value;
}
```

Then you can use "window.communicate.value" anywhere in your processing.js code.

Comment: With Processing.js it's best to use a property of the Processing class so the same as you have above but you need to first set window.Processing.data = {} then you can add and retrieve from anywhere. Your Processing.js script is still just javascript so the variable can be called and set the usual way.

Comment: do i need to restate the variable as a global variable and in the setup() function? After a few different tries the best I can get is slider that stays locked in place.

Comment: can you post the latest code that your working with... maybe post the page online or something and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working demo if it helps:

http://matrix.senecac.on.ca/~asalga/FSOSS2010/jQueryUI/jquery-test.html

Comment: this is somewhat helpful, but i can't see your actual sketch from the source code.